# Allow electron `requires` to passthrough untouched in Vite

Tags: javascript, electron, vite

When trying to use `custom-electron-titlebar` , I get an error when it tries to access `path` . I've added

```js
build: { rollupOptions: { external: ["electron", ...builtinModules],   }}
```

to my vite config, and that seems to allow me to `require('path')` in my own code just fine, but when the imported code inside `custom-electron-titlebar` tries to do the same, it fails to work. It appears to be a wrapped/proxy object, if I call it directly I get an error.

```
Module "path" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code.
```

Is there a way to get these requires to passthrough as well?

Comment: A deeper look reveals that `require("electron")` works, but `import` doesn't. So maybe I need to figure out how to make `import("electron").then(...` actually just translate to `require`... Right now it seems like it's trying to wrap `electron` itself.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [vitejs/vite#2985](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2985), the plugin [vite-plugin-commonjs-externals](https://github.com/xiaoxiangmoe/vite-plugin-commonjs-externals) can fix this for us. In vite.config.js:

```js
import commonjsExternals from 'vite-plugin-commonjs-externals';
export default {
  plugins: commonjsExternals({
    externals: ['path'],
  }),
};
```

Comment: I'm starting from [vite-electron-builder-react](https://github.com/moodiest/vite-electron-builder-react), and that solution doesn't solve the issue. I just can't figure it out! Any suggestions?